# Cannot loop the item in the second path have access

Tags: c#

I encounter the problem the variable of component cannot loops start from second mht path.Example File contains (file1.mht, file2.mht, file3.mht). Maybe the contain inside is (aaaaaa, bbbbbb, cccccc) follow the sequence of the file. Example out output: file1.mht aaaaaa file2.mht bbbbbb file3.mht cccccc

Cuurent result is:
Example: file1.mht aaaaaa file2.mht aaaaaa file3.mht aaaaaa file1.mht aaaaaa

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DirectoryInfo mht_file = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\manchunl\Desktop\ADVI-test\");
            string mht_text = "";

            foreach (FileInfo f in mht_file.GetFiles("*.mht"))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(f.FullName))
                    {
                        string line;

                        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            if (line.EndsWith("="))
                            {
                                line = line.Substring(0, line.Length - 1);
                            }
                            mht_text += line;
                        }
                    }

                    int start_index = mht_text.IndexOf("<HTML ");
                    int end_index = mht_text.IndexOf("</HTML>");

                    mht_text = mht_text.Substring(start_index, end_index + 7 - start_index);

                    mht_text = mht_text.Replace("=0D", "");
                    mht_text = mht_text.Replace("=00", "");
                    mht_text = mht_text.Replace("=0A", "");
                    mht_text = mht_text.Replace("=3D", "=");

                    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
                    doc.LoadHtml(mht_text);

                    var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[3]");
                    string component = table.SelectSingleNode(".//tr[4]").SelectSingleNode(".//td[2]").InnerHtml;

                    Console.WriteLine(f.FullName + "  " + component);

                    File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\manchunl\Desktop\ADVI-test\result\dataCollection.txt", f.FullName + component + Environment.NewLine);

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }

            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Note that the `visual-studio` tag is for questions about the Visual Studio application itself, not code created with it. :)

Comment: Is this question different to your previous question in any way? Also, an empty try/catch is _almost never_ a good idea.

Comment: @John previous one is cannot loop the file name... now this is cannot loop item inside the file start from second one

Comment: Can you remove the `try/catch` and see if you get any exceptions? If you do, provide the full exception as an edit to your question and indicate where the exception was thrown.

Comment: @John already remove the try catch. Still same result as the question

Comment: What happens if you step through with the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

General advice: minimize scope of variables. You use `mht_text` inside a loop and it shouldn't be shared between iterations.

Your error is that `string mht_text = "";` is declared outside the loop. In result it's not empty on the second iteration.

First iteration: `mht_text = "<HTML>aaaaaa</HTML>"`.

Second iteration: `mht_text = "<HTML>aaaaaa</HTML><HTML>bbbbbbb</HTML>"`.

`startIndex` and `endIndex` find the first HTML tag.